# Uncertain of what instance should be passed to the argument

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ipython

Error Message

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<string>", line 20, in set_training_data_directory
  File "<string>", line 252, in printer
AttributeError: 'Navigate' object has no attribute 'Listbox1'
```

In this code, If I call the function set_training_data_directory, it should also call printer from the Toplevel1 which it does. However, as the method printer is expecting self as an argument, any instance from the Navigate class that I pass as an object says "object has no attribute 'Listbox1". I've passed self and self.main_g as an argument and so far the error I get is "object has no attribute 'Listbox1"

Module Name: All_Classes

```
import import_ipynb
import Navigator
import Listings
import Main_GUI
```

Module name: Main

```
from tkinter import *
import import_ipynb
import Main_GUI
root = Tk()
top = Main_GUI.Toplevel1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Module name: Listings

```
import import_ipynb
from tkinter import filedialog
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import os
import All_Classes

class Lists:
    #Making a Navigator Object
    #List of the training data
    def get_list_of_training_data(self):
        training_data_names = []
        directory = self.get_training_dir()        
        for classes in os.listdir(directory):
            for data in os.listdir(os.path.join(directory,classes)):
                print(data)
                training_data_names.append(data)
        return training_data_names
```

Module name: Navigator

```
import import_ipynb
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
import All_Classes

class Navigate:  
    def __init__(self):
        #Global Navigation variables
        #Training data directory
        self.TRAINING_DIR = ''
        #Model directory for loading
        self.MODEL_DIR = ''
        #Sound file path for loading
        self.SOUND_FILE = ''

        self.listings = All_Classes.Listings.Lists

        #self.g = GUI.Toplevel1()
        self.main_g = All_Classes.Main_GUI.Toplevel1

    #Function for Data directory
    def set_training_data_directory(self):
        self.TRAINING_DIR = filedialog.askdirectory()
        p = self.listings.get_list_of_training_data(self)
        print(p)
        self.main_g.printer(self)

    def get_training_dir(self):
        return self.TRAINING_DIR
```

Module Name: Main_GUI

```
import import_ipynb
import All_Classes
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
py3 = True

class Toplevel1:  
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        self.nav = All_Classes.Navigator.Navigate()
        #'''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
        #  top is the,  toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85' 
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92' 
        self.style = ttk.Style()

        top.geometry("832x674+650+150")


        self.style.configure('TNotebook.Tab', background=_bgcolor)
        self.style.configure('TNotebook.Tab', foreground=_fgcolor)
        self.style.map('TNotebook.Tab', background=
        [('selected', _compcolor), ('active',_ana2color)])
        self.TNotebook1 = ttk.Notebook(top)
        self.TNotebook1.place(relx=0.012, rely=0.0, relheight=0.895
               , relwidth=0.978)
        self.TNotebook1.configure(width=814)
        self.TNotebook1.configure(takefocus="")
        self.TNotebook1_t0 = tk.Frame(self.TNotebook1)
        self.TNotebook1.add(self.TNotebook1_t0, padding=3)


        self.TNotebook2 = ttk.Notebook(self.TNotebook1_t0)
        self.TNotebook2.place(relx=0.037, rely=0.113, relheight=0.461
                , relwidth=0.412)
        self.TNotebook2.configure(width=334)
        self.TNotebook2.configure(takefocus="")
        self.TNotebook2_t0 = tk.Frame(self.TNotebook2)
        self.TNotebook2.add(self.TNotebook2_t0, padding=3)
        self.TNotebook2.tab(0, text="Audio Files", compound="left", underline="-1"
                ,)
        self.TNotebook2_t0.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.TNotebook2_t0.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.TNotebook2_t0.configure(highlightcolor="black")


        self.Button2 = tk.Button(self.TNotebook1_t0)
        self.Button2.place(relx=0.123, rely=0.78, height=40, width=190)
        self.Button2.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.Button2.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button2.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button2.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Button2.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button2.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button2.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button2.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button2.configure(text='''Load Training Data''')
        self.Button2.configure(command= self.nav.set_training_data_directory)

        self.Listbox1 = tk.Listbox(self.TNotebook2_t0)
        self.Listbox1.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relheight=1.008, relwidth=1.012)
        self.Listbox1.configure(background="white")
        self.Listbox1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Listbox1.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Listbox1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Listbox1.configure(width=334)
        #Init Scrollbar object
        self.scroll1 = tk.Scrollbar(self.Listbox1)
        self.scroll1.configure(command=self.Listbox1.yview)
        self.Listbox1.configure(yscrollcommand = self.scroll1.set)

    def printer(self): 
        print("printer Reached")

        self.Listbox1.pack()
        self.scroll1.pack(side = "right",fill = 'y')

        for i in range(20):
            self.Listbox1.insert(tk.END,i)
```

I am pretty new with object in python. If you happen to have an answer, I would appreciate it. Also could this be a bad way of designing?

Comment: This code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @figbeam I apologise as it looks lengthy. The main focus is in the Navigate class within the set_training_data_directory method. Over there is where i call the function printer which belongs to module Main_GUI. Also these codes should be in different module. Let me know if anything and thank you

Comment: The reason the code should be complete (runnable) is because we run it to see whats up. The code should also be minimal so it's not full of irrelevant bits. By using several custom modules we have to do a lot of extra work just to get it running. The module `PopupGUI` is missing and what is `import_ipynb` and is it really necessary to produce the error?

Comment: @figbeam I apologise once more. I hate to make you guys go through this trouble but I've spend so much time trying to fix it because I know it would be annoying posting all this code. Unfortunately, it is necessary to produce the error because I don't know any other way to explain it, other than the explanation I gave prior. As for PopupGUI you can remove it from All_Classes and it should run. I tested it. import_ipynb has to be installed. For instances, I am using jupyter notebook and I installed it from anaconda prompt.

Comment: So,tell me a little about your environment. I installed `import_ipynb`, `IPython` and now it's complaining about `No module named 'nbformat'`. Cn you show a list of dependencies?

Comment: @figbeam I read about it and it seems to be for the implemetation of jupyter notebook format. As for my environment, I am using jupyter notebook 5.7.4 and the type of files I am using is python 3. I understand dependencies, but in this case, I don't know what else to provide other than the list of imports which are in the code. Another thing about 'nbformat', I saw that people can install it, maybe that will fix it?

Comment: Fixed it. Well, it runs but I'm getting: `AttributeError: 'Navigate' object has no attribute 'get_training_dir'` when I select dir for training data.

Comment: @figbeam I am searching up how to fix this problem and I noticed that many people post the error message they get. Sorry for that, I should have posted it in the first place. It is on the very top of this page.

Comment: @figbeam I added the get_training_dir which was missing in the from the navigate class.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I had a look, and it definitely seems to be a issue with how you write and use classes. In `Navigator` you call the `Lists` class, but you don't instanciate it:

```
self.listings = All_Classes.Listings.Lists
```

To make an instance you must end the class name with parenthesis. Thus when you run the method `get_list_of_training_data(self)` there is no self to pass as self is the name of the instance.

Same thing with `self.main_g = All_Classes.Main_GUI.Toplevel1`.

From my perspective it looks like you build a complicated structure of classes when you really don't need them. To quote Jack Diederich: "The signature of **this is not a class** is that it has two methods, one of which is init". YouTube clip: [Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)

On my end I'm having trouble to get it running without errors because my `os.path.join()` delivers dysfunctional paths, don't know why.

But: have look and see if you can make the code not so fractured and I think it will be easier to spot problems.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. This is a really bad way of making the instances in python which I am learning now. I will change my approach and keep you in the loop if you're okay with that.

Comment: Ok. Post it as a new question and add a comment to this question with a link.